# Ascending, Descending - variable string in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I got an association with Cinema and Location in my model.

There is a problem with the following:

@locations = Location.find(:all, :order => location.cinema.name)

But its not working, i am trying to order it by the name which is located in the cinema table. I would even love it within the html.erb page as well if its possible.

What i am trying to do is arrange location.cinema.name in ascending, descending order

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to join in the Cinema in your Location query. Also, since you're on Rails 3, you can use the newer `where(..)`, `order(...)`, etc. format rather than `find(:all, :order => ...)`:

```
@locations = Location.joins(:cinema).order("cinemas.name").all
```

Comment: Thanks a billion Dylan! appreciate it